# Facing issues while handling Windows Pop-up using Selenium C# with AutoIT script

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, autoit-c#-wrapper

I am using a test website "http://www.engprod-charter.net" in **chrome** **browser** to handle windows based authentication pop up.

Script written in SciTE editor of **AutoIT** is as follows and works perfectly if I manually open the website and then run the script from the editor.

```
ControlFocus("https://www.engprod-charter.net/api/pub/cnetloginedge/spectrum-redir?targetUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.engprod-spectrum.net%2F%3Fdomain-redirect%3Dtrue - Google Chrome","Chrome Legacy Window","Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1")
WinWaitActive("https://www.engprod-charter.net/api/pub/cnetloginedge/spectrum-redir?targetUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.engprod-spectrum.net%2F%3Fdomain-redirect%3Dtrue - Google Chrome")
Send("admin{TAB}admin{ENTER}")
```

But unfortunately I am failing to automate it using Selenium-C#.
Here is my code.

```
IWebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
d.Manage().Window.Maximize();
d.Url = "https://www.engprod-charter.net";
Process.Start("C:\\Users\\AutoIt Scripts\\Engprod.exe");
```

I had also alternatively tried the below code which didn't help me.

```
IWebDriver d = new ChromeDriver();
d.Manage().Window.Maximize();
d.Url = "https://www.engprod-charter.net";
AutoItX3 AutoIt = new AutoItX3();
AutoIt.ControlFocus("https://www.engprod-charter.net/api/pub/cnetloginedge/spectrum-redir?targetUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.engprod-spectrum.net%2F%3Fdomain-redirect%3Dtrue - Google Chrome", "Chrome Legacy Window", "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND1");
AutoIt.WinWaitActive("https://www.engprod-charter.net/api/pub/cnetloginedge/spectrum-redir?targetUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.engprod-spectrum.net%2F%3Fdomain-redirect%3Dtrue - Google Chrome");
AutoIt.Send("Abhi{TAB}admin{ENTER}");
```

How to handle windows based pop-up using Selenium?

Comment: Your alternative would not work. You will have to use `Engprod.exe` only. Now what happens when you run  the exe from your code ? Does it throw any exception/error ?

Comment: It works when i run the .exe file.
But through my code , it isnt working.

Comment: That you have already mentioned, what is the error exception ?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:57927/session/40d66a7861d529c5468def1c3ff90f13/url timed out after 60 seconds.

Comment: @cruisepandey, The actual script, and my alternate approach are working as expected in IE and Firefox browsers through my code. The problem is only with Chrome Browser.

Comment: I am afraid, I can help you out.